# Proper Implementation of JDBC Multithreading with JNDI

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, jndi

I'm working on a project where I'm doing a lot of queries and time is a consideration so I want to try and implement JDBC multithreading. I'm not sure what the proper way to do this is.

Here's my first draft implementation:

**Spring Datasource Bean:**

```
private DataSource ds;
@Resource(name="jdbc")
public void setDataSource(DataSource ds) {
    this.ds = ds;
}
```

**Initialization method:**

```
  public void checkUsersMulti(List<User> users) throws Exception {
    if(users!= null || users.size() != 0) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
        Queue<User> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
        queue.addAll(users);
        for (Useruser: users) {
            executorService.submit(new ProcessUser(queue));
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        try {
            executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**Runnable Class:**

```
class ProcessUser implements Runnable {
    private final Queue<User> queue;

    public ProcessUser(Queue<User> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
            User user = null;
            while((user = queue.poll()) != null) {
                userDao.getUser(user , conn));
            }
            DbUtils.closeQuietly(conn);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**User DAO method:**

```
public User retrieveUser(User user, Connection conn)  {
    PreparedStatement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM users WHERE id= ?;

        st = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        st.setString(1, user.getId());
        rs = st.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()) {
            user.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstname"));
            user.setLastName(rs.getString("lastname"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
    finally {
        DbUtils.closeQuietly(rs);
        DbUtils.closeQuietly(st);
    }
    return user;
}
```

**UPDATE: Tomcat JNDI Connection Pool Settings:**

```
 <Resource
    name="jdbc"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxTotal ="25"
    maxIdle="30"
    maxWaitMillis ="10000"
    driverClassName="***Vendor Driver***"
    url="***Valid URL"
    username="***Valid Username***"
    password="***Valid Password***"
/>
```

However, I am getting this error occasionally:

`java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object`

But the process still completes as expected - it may be in my JNDI settings. My bigger concern is if this is the "correct" way to implement this. I assumed it was best to hold onto connection object so they don't have to be re-initialized.

Comment: what is the size of `users`? does issue occur for any size of `users`?

Comment: my dataset is ~200 right now, I will try expanding and contracting it to see what the behavior is - I have implemented @rmalchow's suggestions but I am curious to see how it behaves.

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of issues with this code, most importantly, i am not sure what this:

```
   public void checkUsersMulti(List<User> users) throws Exception {
    if(users!= null || users.size() != 0) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
        Queue<User> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
        queue.addAll(users);
        for (Useruser: users) {
            executorService.submit(new ProcessUser(queue));
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        try {
            executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

is supposed to do. if i understand it correctly, you create a queue with ALL of the users in it, and then you submit it to the executor as many times as there are users. this would mean that:

- you are limited in terms of the number of users you can process, because the queue can not grow indefinitely (which is what @sabit khan is probably worried about)
- you have to run the runnable at least ONCE for each user, although unless some runnables exit because of an error, the first 20 will keep running until the queue is empty, and then the remaining will be invoked, see that the queue is empty, and immediately exit.

you should probably limit the number of parallel processes you are starting. you have a thread pool of 20 though, so there should never be more than 20 concurrent connections, if you close your connections properly. you don't mention any other exceptions, but this:

```
    try {
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        User user = null;
        while((user = queue.poll()) != null) {
            userDao.getUser(user , conn));
        }
        DbUtils.closeQuietly(conn);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

should probably be:

```
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = ds.getConnection();
        User user = null;
        while((user = queue.poll()) != null) {
            userDao.getUser(user , conn));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        DbUtils.closeQuietly(conn);
    }
```

just to make sure the connection is closed in any situation.

also, since you're apparently using an underlying connection pool, you might want to try getting and returning the connections every single time.

as to your actual question: the way you're doing this means that the first twenty runnables try to get connections and then hold them for a very long time. if your pool is configured to use provide less connections than that (let's say 15), then this could easily happen, since the first 15 would successfully get a connection, then the next 5 workers would continously run a runnable, try, fail, exit. OR of you use exactly 20 connections in your pool, you might be leaking connections because you're not properly closing them as described above.

Comment: So by doing **(User user: users)**, I'm actually creating a lot of threads...of which 20 actually do something. So I've changed it to  **for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)** . And I updated to the finally as you suggest.  Is the problem with holding connections is that they can timeout and fail?

Comment: I guess to be more direct, what are the pros and cons of holding onto it? I would think there is slightly less overhead in having to go back to the datasource to get a connection...but I don't know what kind of bad situations that could put you in or why it's recommended to return it.

Comment: the duration isn't a big problem, but as @kiresays wrote, there's not much overhead.

Comment: have you run it? how did it go? still exceptions? do you know your connection pool settings?

Comment: First test looks a lot better, but I'm going to do some extensive tests today and next week. I'll update the OP with my connection settings. I will report back - thank you for your help!